# iOS UITextView sizeToFit make height doubled of content text in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, sizetofit

Below is my code of textView, but `sizeToFit` makes textView's height more than doubled of it's content text. Please provide any solution

```
UITextView *paragraphView  = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 295, 30)];
[paragraphView setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[paragraphView setScrollEnabled: NO];
[paragraphView setEditable: NO];
[paragraphView setText: @"hello there ..........hii i am here....."];
[paragraphView setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 30]];

[self.view addSubview: paragraphView];

[paragraphView sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Look at the `textContainerInset` property

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSLayout constraints to frame the UITextview instead of initwithframe.
you may get the content sized height for textview properly